# Kafka streams to consume next message only when acknowledgement is received for first one

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

How to configure Kafka streams to consume next message only when acknowledgement is received for first one. I tried manual commit but that doesn't stop Kafka from receiving messages

Comment: What do you mean by "acknowledgment"? Acks are typically a term used in the Producer API, meanwhile consumers just poll records, not ack they have been polled.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't see any advantage but it will have a huge performance hit. Maybe setting `max.poll.records=1` and `commit.interval.ms=0` does what you want?